# App center build, Error: /usr/bin/jarsigner failed with return code: 1

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

Using app center when I try and build I currently get this error:

```
[command]/usr/bin/jarsigner -keystore /Users/vsts/agent/2.136.1/work/1/s/.certs/keystore.jks -storepass *** -keypass *** -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar /Users/vsts/agent/2.136.1/work/1/s/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk /Users/vsts/agent/2.136.1/work/1/s/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk.unsigned ***
jarsigner: unable to sign jar: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 11019 but got 11226 bytes)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/jarsigner failed with return code: 1
##[error]Return code: 1
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The build is successful, but the pipeline its failing at signing. In your build configuration the environmental variables for the *Keystore password*, the *Key alias* or the *Key password* are not set properly.

Answer (score 10):

In your android/app/build.gradle, make sure you are not providing a signingConfig for the relase config:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // ...
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug <-- should not be used on Appcenter
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, but the resolution was different.

It was due to not having a .gitignore file in my project so both the /Debug and /Release folders were pushed to the repo.

[Build Error issue - helped identify my issue](https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2018/12/12/fixing-appcenter-android-build-error-usr-bin-jarsigner-failed-with-return-code-1/)

[How to add a git ignore in visual studio](https://elanderson.net/2016/09/add-git-ignore-to-existing-visual-studio-project/)